# Ember link-to opens link in the same page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to learn ember routes and created a very simple example app. My application template has this code-

```
{{#link-to "testpage"}}Go to test page.{{/link-to}}
{{outlet}}
```

The testpage was created via ember-cli

```
ember g resource testpage
```

The testpage template contains simple text "This is a testpage".
When I run this app, the main page correctly shows a hyperlink to testpage and upon clicking, the browser URL also changes to localhost:4200/testpage but the testpage text is shown alongwith "Go to test page" hyperlink. Shouldn't it go to a new page?

Also, it might help to note that I am using pod structure in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application template will always render, regardless of which resource/route you've navigated to.  Top-level resources will render in the `{{outlet}}` that you have right there.

If you want the 'Go to test page.' link to be replaced, you'll need to create a separate template for it.  Call it `index.hbs` and it will get rendered automatically for the root path.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll create a new index resource, but how do I tell ember to load index as soon as app opens?